# Insert multiline to file inside docker container from outside

Tags: bash, docker, makefile

I need to save multiline content about xdebug from makefile, but I cannot use file in repo, previosuly I had do this within:

```
docker exec -i $(CONTAINER) bash -c 'cat > /etc/php8/conf.d/50_xdebug.ini' < file
```

But now I need to use variable (multiline) or insert line by line.

```html
xdebug: check-xdebug-env
ifeq ($(XDEBUG_STATUS),1)
    @make xdebug-enable
else
    @make xdebug-disable
endif

xdebug-disable:
    @make restart

xdebug-enable:
    @make restart

restart:
    @docker exec $(CONTAINER) bash -c "kill -9 $(shell $(CMD) ps -a | grep '[p]hp-fpm' | awk '{print $$1}')"
```

Comment: Trying to use `docker exec` to change PHP interpreter config files is probably wrong: since the interpreter is the main container process, you can't restart it without destroying the container, at which point the config file change is lost.  Try adding it in your image's Dockerfile or a `docker run -v` bind mount instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1 for debugging make: remove ALL the `@` prefixes to your recipe lines.  Rule #2: examine the recipe lines make prints carefully and make sure they're the same thing you would run if you were running it by hand.  Anywhere they are different, that's where you have to concentrate on fixing something.

Tip for writing makefiles: if you're using the `$(shell ...)` make function inside a recipe, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

I don't understand what you want to accomplish here and you've left out important parts in your question (what does `$(CMD)` expand to, for example) but remember that make functions, like `$(shell ...)`, are all expanded *by make* **before** it invokes any command in the recipe.  So this script is run on your host system, before make invokes the `docker` command.  It's not run inside the container.  That's probably not what you want.

```
restart:
        docker exec $(CONTAINER) bash -c 'kill -9 $$($(CMD) ps -a | grep "[p]hp-fpm" | awk "{print \$$1}")'
```